# When spreading the prevstate of a React useState hook I'm recieveing the error: must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having the following problem when trying to spread the prevstate of a React useState Hook.

Here is the code that is showing the problem:

`setSelectedMetrics((prevState) => [...prevState, metric]);`

I'm receiving this error when I'm trying to spread the prevState:

**Type 'IMetrics[] | undefined' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)**

Here is where I set up the state:

`const [selectedMetrics, setSelectedMetrics] = useState<ISelectedMetrics[] | undefined>([]);`

The state selectedMetrics comes from the parent component as props to its child component, where I consume the state.

Here is the type that I've created to selectedMetrics:

```
export interface ISelectedMetrics {
  metricPath: string;
  displayName?: string;
}
```

If anyone had been through this issue before and could help, I would appreciate it.

I already tried to find a solution in the community for this specif issue when spreading the prevstate of a React useState hook array, but I didn't find any applicable solution.

Comment: Why is `undefined` included in the type definition for the state value?

Comment: The cause of the issue is the combination of `strictNullChecks` in your settings and `| undefined` in your type definition.

Comment: @David thanks man, I wasn't seen this in my code. In some part of my code I was using a table with a check all checkbox where the value of metricPath was undefined. I fixed it passing a metricPath as an empty string, and removing the undefined of it's type definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem based on David answer. In some part of my code I was using selectedMetrics state to populate a table with some checkboxes. I've implemented some global checkbox to check all checkboxes, but this global checkbox didn't have a metricPath, so I defined it as undefined an pass it to a function as undefined.
The solution was remove the undefined from the type definition and fix the logic of the global checkbox to pass a metricPath with empty string, so when spreading the prevstate it didn't compare it to undefined.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you cannot spread an object into an array

```js
var x = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'};
var y = [...x];
console.log(y);
```

`"Uncaught TypeError: x is not iterable"`

Comment: He is not spreading a object, but an array of objects --> spreading an array